# recursively get property names of an object/record

Tags: typescript

Given an object of the form {...} - not a primitive or array - I want to generate a type that is the literal property names in that type. I've tried doing this with mapped types, but can't get it right. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I can go one-level deep (this is actually easy using the keyof operator) but can't figure out how to do it recursively. I know I'm close, because in my example below if the `email` property is NOT optional, it works. So somehow it is getting tripped up on optional properties.

```
type PropertyNames<
  T extends Record<string, unknown>,
  MODE extends 'deep' | 'shallow'
> = {
  [KEY in keyof T & (string | number )]:
    | KEY
    | (MODE extends 'deep'
        ? T[KEY] extends Record<string, unknown>
          ? PropertyNames<T[KEY], 'deep'>
          : never
        : never);
}[keyof T & (string | number)];

type Email = {
  address: string;
  verified: boolean;
};

type UserToken = {
  uid: string;
  name?: string;
  email?: Email;
};

// Expected: uid | name | email | address | verified
// Actual  : uid | name | email
type DeepNames = PropertyNames<UserToken, 'deep'>;

// Expected and Actual : uid | name | email
type ShallowNames = PropertyNames<UserToken, 'shallow'>;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your main problem is that `T[KEY] extends Record<string, unknown> ? ...` is not [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over possible unions in `T[KEY]`, and so when `KEY` is an optional property, `T[KEY]` will include `undefined`, and since `undefined extends Record<string, unknown>` is not true, the whole thing fails and you get `never`.  It would be better to use a formulation that distributes over unions.

My inclination would be to do something like this:

```
type PropertyNames<T, M extends 'deep' | 'shallow'> =
    T extends object ?
    { [K in keyof T]-?: K |
        (M extends 'deep' ? PropertyNames<T[K], "deep"> : never)
    }[keyof T] : never
```

or, if you have array types mixed in there, this:

```
type PropertyNames<T, M extends 'deep' | 'shallow'> =
    T extends object ?
    { [K in keyof T]-?: K |
        (M extends 'deep' ? PropertyNames<T[K], "deep"> : never)
    }[Extract<keyof T, T extends readonly any[] ? number : unknown>] : never
```

Which yields this for your example:

```
type DeepNames = PropertyNames<UserToken, 'deep'>;
// type DeepNames = "uid" | "name" | "email" | "address" | "verified"
```

as desired.

---

The changes I made:

- I've ditched `Record<string, unknown>` for the less problematic `object`, since `interface` types without index signatures tend not to be assignable to `Record<string, unknown>`:

  ```
  interface Oops {
    x: string;
  }

  type Nope = Oops extends Record<string, unknown> ? "yep" : "nope";
  // type Nope = "nope"
  ```
- I've dropped the restriction on `T` being an object type; this makes it easier to do the recursive evaluation on `PropertyNames<T[K]>`; if `T` is not an object then just return `never`.  This also automatically distributes the operation over unions in `T`.  While `T[K] extends ...` does not distribute, `T extends ...` does because `T` is a "bare" type parameter.
- I've made the mapped type turn all properties into required ones with [the `-?` modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers); this will cut out any weird `undefined`s that might appear in the final output.
- I've replaced `keyof T & (string | number)` with `keyof T` since unless we're trying to forbid `symbol` keys I don't think it matters much.
- The thing with `Extract<keyof T, T extends readonly any[] ? number : unknown>` is just to deal with arrays; you presumably don't want to see all the names of the array methods like `"push"` or `"pop"` in your output (if you do then you can just use `keyof T` instead).  So for arrays, just look at the properties at numeric indices.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTge0nUA5AhgWwgZwDwAqANFALJQQAewEAdgCY5QDk9EEYzUAPizgBboANkIQB3ZgD4oAXgCwAKCjKoBCtTqMoCAEYArCAGNgUAPyKVUAN5QA2gGkoAS1pQA1hBAIAZqoC6ALSmAFxQjtwWlioAFORUNAxMrOycZrCIyGhYuIQOfiQARGwcBdKhtBAAbhBwAJSRygC+tgCi1HDoxngeXr7EquoJWnAQ6PQItEIgUOi0ILZ+abQArpg6NVChy7RutOK0kovlVTWKiqCQUC2Y6E5CstYNM-T0Izg4oTjAcC4A5gDcT2qP28Tgg9FCOgQCCEo1ogIUjQR53A0AAqjgagQEB5XDJHkoVMsnBCoF8frQAU9aNkQmTvn8EZYIDc7nTrrchAikWcFBdoAARFIYbBMfHwJA1LKivAYrE4ugkZIcKQIgD0aqg-KgQo4ItwDwKxPoBR4UAKNOwpt4BRZnOt5rGr1wOAdBWBTlB4IKvI1V0okGM4JmDCgAEFjMthJsoMazZboLw7XcUZcAMqCETifVi9KSlAgHOyzFwbG4pUCYSiCSSZEKRQuGhwbydaAAeSQTCsT0onwZlO5vO1qElDw7YCY8U0TAASkYEHB6HhyX8SNtdvtpKZzSASjGLZKCurNcPR-iD5ACkA)

Comment: Perfect super useful answer. I figured out my own version - wrapping every T with Required<T> but yours is shorter and I really appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is fairly similar to your implementation but requires all the keys of any object type being passed to `PropertyNames`.

```js
type Email = {
  address: string;
  verified: boolean;
};

type UserToken = {
  uid: string;
  name?: string;
  email?: Email;
};

type PropertyNames<T, MODE extends "deep" | "shallow"> =
  | keyof T
  | {
      [K in keyof T]-?: Required<T>[K] extends Record<string, any>
        ? MODE extends "shallow"
          ? never
          : PropertyNames<Required<T>[K], MODE>
        : never;
    }[keyof T];

// uid | name | email | address | verified
type DeepNames = PropertyNames<UserToken, "deep">;

// uid | name | email
type ShallowNames = PropertyNames<UserToken, "shallow">;
```

Comment: Thanks. I see how this fixes the problem with my solution - wrapping in Required.